# Same product name in different categories

Tags: seo, url, ecommerce, best-practices

I have two questions about URL structure for SEO.

1. I have one product belongs to multiple categories. Is this OK for SEO OR shall I give them different product names?

   1. example.com/shirts/denim/poloshirt.html
   2. example.com/shirts/pinkcolor/poloshirt.html
2. Is it good or to put numeric product code in the URL as this:

   1. example.com/shirts/denim/shirt-st397.html
   2. example.com/shirts/denim/shirt-sw160.html

Google regard it as one product or different products?

Comment: You can find an answer to the first question here: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/15878/content-appearing-under-multiple-categories-anything-i-can-do-to-prevent-duplic

Answer (score 2):

Most modern eCommerce shopping carts give you the option to include the categories in the URL or remove them leaving only `http://example.com/poloshirt.html` this way no matter which category links to it it's not a unique URL for each.

I would personally avoid a product code in URL's if possible.

Answer (score 0):

Some people actually do search by product codes, for more faster and precise search results, such as the UPC code or SKU. Are your product codes unique? Meaning that one product code per a product? I've seen cases where similar products with just a color difference, share the same product code.

Answer (score 0):

Your information architecture is not alright if you need to deal this situation.

use the [canonical meta tag](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.co.il/2009/02/specify-your-canonical.html) to tell search engines it is the same page. (it really should be, despite the different categories. they all should lead to this exact page with exactly one unique URL)